# How to implement calculated field in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have an entity OrderLine with fields unitPrice, quantity and totalPrice. And totalPrice value is calculated: totalPrice=unitPrice*quantity.

totalPrice is a persisted field.

i want to display totalPrice as an ouputtext in the view.

First alternative:
`<h:outputText id="total"  value="#{unitPrice*quantity}"/>`    with this alternative the entity field totalPrice will not be never updated, but in the view the correct value of the total price will be displayed.

second alternative:`<h:outputText id="total"  value="#{orderLine.totalPrice }"/>`

With this alternative the value fetched from the database will be display, but this value will be always null.

Is it possible using only JSF, to display the value #{orderLine.totalPrice } when the page is display, and to set it's updated value #{unitPrice*quantity} when unitPrice or quantity are modified in the same page?

Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I would probably try to do it on the client side with some JavaScript with jQuery.

But if you really want to do it with plain Java & JSF, one thing you can do is to update the field `totalPrice` whenever one of the fields `unitPrice` or `quantity` is updated:

```
public void setUnitPrice(BigDecimal unitPrice) {
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    this.updateTotalPrice();
}
public void setQuantity(BigDecimal quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.updateTotalPrice();
}
private void updateTotalPrice() {
    // update total price accordingly:
    if (unitPrice != null && quantity != null){
        this.totalPrice = this.unitPrice.multiply(this.quantity);
    }
}
```

This way you would also have your model always up-to-date.

Then you just need to rerender the component displaying it with ajax, on the event `onchange` of the `unitPrice` and `quantity` form controls, something like this:

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <label>Unit Price</label>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.unitPrice}">
        <f:convertNumber type="currency" />
        <f:ajax render="totalPrice" />
    </h:inputText>
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.quantity}">
        <f:convertNumber type="currency" />
        <f:ajax render="totalPrice" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:outputText id="totalPrice" value="#{myBean.totalPrice}">
        <f:convertNumber type="currency" />
    </h:outputText>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: @Belin You're welcome! If you liked my answer, you can accept it clicking the V that appears on the left side. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using directly the entity you probably need to use wrapper to put the logic in the wrapped getTotalPrice method.  This way you have a better logic/presentation separation, in you case you will be able to add rounding logic to the getTotalPrice (most of the time the IEEE floating math doesn't fit for money related math...)